# SQL-Show that R is not in Boyce-Codd Normal Form

Tags: sql, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

`R = (J,K,L,M,N)` with a set of functional dependencies `{J->KL,LM->N,K->M,N->J}`.

I understand the definition of BCNF. I believe that there exists no trivial functional dependencies and there may not be a super key. I'm not sure about the second part. How would you determine a super key from letters? Would appreciate some input on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation would be in Boyce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF), if the closure of the left-side attributes for all functional dependencies contains all relation attributes `(J, K, L, M, N)`. In other words, the left-side attributes of each functional dependency contain a key.

Let's analyze your functional dependencies:

1. `J -> KL`. Then `K -> M`, then `LM -> N` and `N -> J`. So, `J ->
   KL` satisfies BCNF.
2. `LM -> N`. Then `N -> J`, then `J -> KL` and
   that is all, we have all attributes.
3. `K -> M`. This functional
   dependency is obviously a violation of BCNF, because we cannot get
   more attributes from set of dependencies.
4. `N -> J`. Then `J -> KL` and `K -> M`. It satisfies BCNF.

So, the third dependency violates BCNF and `K` attribute is not the key itself.

Comment: To be more specific, left-hand side of attributes must be "superkey".